# Xcode: PosterBoard quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode

On macOS Monterey (12.5.1 (21G83)), using Xcode 14.0 beta 6 (14A5294g), when unit testing vs iOS simulator, I get a lot of `PosterBoard quit unexpectedly` warnings.

This is a project with many SPM packages and then I have an Xcode Proj using these local SPM packages as dependecy. I've set the `testTarget` from Package.swift (the tests of the local SPM packages) to run when unit testing the app (the scheme for the Xcode Proj). maybe that setup is causing issues?

[Also seen on Reddit /r/Xcode](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcode/comments/wcd9wc/xcode_14_beta_4_simulator_crashing_posterboard/) but non of the comments fixed the issue for me. I cannot set deployment to iOS 16, because need to support iOS 15 (some comment in the Reddit thread suggested that might solve it).

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am getting this message.